# Is it possible to Facebook LIKE URL without knowing OBJECT_ID and without the facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Basicly I want to do the same what Facebook API does but without the API. Any ideas?

Comment: You should try to get more information into your question. You might want to add links to the subject so we can get to know what you have tried, or where you are stuck, so we can help you out. People won't generaly respond to such vague questions, specially because they show little effort from the person who's asking. I suggest showing some of the options you're considering to get people interested in the subject.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want s to add a facebook like button to your website, then you can use the "like button generator" here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Use the "get code" button at the bottom.

If you need to like different pages, then it's easy to grab the code (as per above) and just programmatically substitute in your URL for the one you put in the code above.

If you need anything more than this, you will need to provide us more information. Starting with what language you use, what you've already tried and what form you'd like the "LIKE URL" to be in when you're done.

Comment: Of note: if you use the iframe version of the like plugin, then you wont have to include the js sdk API in your webpage as you would if you use HTML5 or XFBML versions of the like plugin.